# How do I create a deep copy of a double pointer referring to a different class (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, copy-constructor

as you may have figured I'm a bit new to the copy-construcor and so far I'm understanding the general concept of it but I have little to no idea about the syntax itself.
I have a class called Yahtzee which is linked with two other classes, *Protocol though a double pointer*, and *Dice though a dynamic array*. My goal is to make a copy of Yahtzee through the copy-constructor but I'm having some trouble with how handle the double pointers.

Relevant code:

```
class Yatzee {
private:
    int nrOfPlayers;
    int playerPos;
    int currentPlayer;
    Dice *dices[DICE];    //int DICE = 5
    Protocol ** playerProtocols;
public:
    Yatzee(int nrOfPlayers = 2);
    Yatzee(const Yatzee &object);
    //Yatzee& operator=(const Yatzee& object) const;
    Yatzee& operator=(const Yatzee& object);
    ~Yatzee();
    void addPlayer(string name);
};
```

So far I've had zero problems with the Dice class but when it comes to the syntax of *playerprotocols* I'm having quite some trouble. Everything that's // is my trails and errors.

```
Yatzee::Yatzee(const Yatzee & object) {
nrOfPlayers = object.nrOfPlayers;
playerPos = object.playerPos;
currentPlayer = object.currentPlayer;
if (object.playerProtocols) {
    playerProtocols = new Protocol*[object.nrOfPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < object.nrOfPlayers; i++) {
        //behöver skapa ny men behöver också samtidigt få med informationen från tidigare objectet
        //playerProtocols[i] = new Protocol();
        //använd copy constructor från Protocol här men hur?
        //new Protocol(object.playerProtocols[i]);
        //playerProtocols[i] = object.playerProtocols[i];
        this->playerProtocols[i] = new Protocol(object.playerProtocols[i]); //should work
        //new Protocol(playerProtocols[i], object.playerProtocols[i]);
        //Protocol * playerProtocols[i] = new Protocol(object.playerProtocols[i]);
        //new(&playerProtocols[i])Protocol(object.playerProtocols[i]);
        //new(&dstObject) Object(&anotherObject);


        //Object * obj = new Object(anotherObject);   // not &anotherObject
        //Object obj2(anotherObject);
        //this->abc[i] = new ProtocolColumn(det andraobjektet.abc[i])
    }
}
else {
    playerProtocols = 0;
}
for (int i = 0; i < DICE; i++) {
    //dices[i] = object.dices[i];
    dices[i] = new Dice();
}
```

From my understanding and based on the error message *no instance of constructor matches the argument list* I figured my copy-constructor in Protocol lacks the proper syntax but I don't really know how to fix it.

Here the copy-constructor I'm refering to. I tried fixing it with * instead of & but that didnt not work and instead I got the error cdcdcdcd.

```
Protocol::Protocol(const Protocol &oldProtocol) {
name = oldProtocol.name;
totalSum = oldProtocol.totalSum;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    scoreboard[i] = oldProtocol.scoreboard[i];
    spotTaken[i] = oldProtocol.spotTaken[i];
}
}
Protocol::Protocol(const Protocol *object){
    name = object->name;
    totalSum = object->totalSum;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    scoreboard[i] = object->scoreboard[i];
    spotTaken[i] = object->spotTaken[i];
    }
```

I'm sure the answer is obvious but I can't quite put my finger on it. I would appreciate any help I could get.

EDIT** I added code for the constructors

```
Yatzee::Yatzee(int nrOfPlayers) {
    this->nrOfPlayers = nrOfPlayers;
    this->playerPos = 0;
    this->currentPlayer = 0;
    this->playerProtocols = new Protocol*[nrOfPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < DICE; i++) {
        this->dices[i] = new Dice();
    }
}
```

and Protocol in case it's needed

```
class Protocol {
private:
    string name;
    int totalSum;
    int scoreboard[SIZE];
    bool spotTaken[SIZE];
public:
    explicit Protocol(string name = "?");
    Protocol(const Protocol &object);
    Protocol& operator=(const Protocol& object);
    ~Protocol();
};


Protocol::Protocol(string name) {
    this->name = name;
    this->totalSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        this->scoreboard[i] = 0;
        this->spotTaken[i] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fixed the wrong thing, leave the `Protocol` copy constructor alone

```
this->playerProtocols[i] = new Protocol(object.playerProtocols[i]); //should work
```

should be

```
this->playerProtocols[i] = new Protocol(*(object.playerProtocols[i])); // will work
```

It's a double pointer, so to get to the actual object you need two dereferences, `*` and `[i]`.

Now it should be clear, pointers are hard work. The real lesson should be to rewrite your classes without raw pointers. Use smart pointers if you need to but avoid raw pointers. Mind you I can't see any reason in the posted code that you need pointers at all.

Without raw pointers, your copy constructor and assignment operator will *literally write themselves*.

Comment: it's for a class assingment and one of the requirements was that we used doublepointers but yes I agree with you, it's really not needed. I tried what you mentioned (and I'm sure it's right) but now I get an "read access violation. **_Right_data** was 0xCDCDCDCD". Do I have to change anything in the Protocol copy-constructor as well or maybe in any of the assignment operators?(didn't post them beacause they didnt seem relevant for the errors)

Comment: That error means that one of your pointers is uninitialised (0xCDCDCDCD is the value that the Microsoft compiler gives to uninitialised heap data). It's likely to be something wrong in the way you set up the pointers in the first place, rather than an error in the copy constructor. Can't tell from the posted code however.

Comment: Sounds like you have a tutor who believes that learning about pointers and dynamic memory allocation is good for your soul. That's reasonable as long as you don't think that this style of programming is what you should be aiming for. Most of the time good programmers avoid raw pointers.

Comment: Oh okey that could exsplain a lot. But are you refering to how I'm declaring them or how they are created in the constructor? Or possibly both? It's good to hear raw pointers are normally avoided, not the biggest fan of them so far.

Comment: How they are created in the constructor I would guess, although I can't see your code (I'm not pyschic).

Comment: right right, my bad, I have added it now. First time I'm using stackoverflow

Comment: Well this is the problem `this->playerProtocols = new Protocol*[nrOfPlayers];`, you create an array of pointers, but you don't give the pointers themselves any values. That's why they all have value 0xCDCDCDCD. You need something like this `this->playerProtocols = new Protocol*[nrOfPlayers]; for (int i = 0; i < nrOfPlayers; ++i) this->playerProtocols[i] = new Protocol();` Though where you get the name for the protocol I'm not sure.

Comment: An alternative would be `this->playerProtocols = new Protocol*[nrOfPlayers]; for (int i = 0; i < nrOfPlayers; ++i) this->playerProtocols[i] = nullptr;` if you wanted to create the protocols later, but then you have to deal with null pointers in your copy constructor.

Comment: it works now! I got playerProtocols from a diffrent function but I had no idea that I needed to create them in the constructor first. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @PumpkinSteph Glad it works. You don't *have* to create the protocol objects in the constructor, it's entirely up to you where you create them. But just be aware that they won't create themselves. Whenever you have a pointer it's you that has to make it point at something.